# Whitespace is clickable with href image's

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, href, center

I am using bootstrap framework.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/link"><img src="images/placeholder-200x200.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-rounded center-block"></a>
            Step 1: Credit & Money
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/link"><img src="images/placeholder-200x200.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-rounded center-block"></a>
            Step 1: Credit & Money
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a href="/link"><img src="images/placeholder-200x200.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-rounded center-block"></a>
            Step 1: Credit & Money
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Whitespace on the left and right sides of the images are also clickable - looks like .center-block is the culprit. How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A block spans the entire div, and centers by using margin. As a link, I would suggest instead removing the center-block from the images themselves, creating a class:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and setting that class on the containing div, in your case:

```
<div class="col-md-4 center">
```

Or something similiar.

Also I would suggest placing your text description for each image into a div, since without the image being a block, the text would flow next to it. Simply placing the text in a paragraph tag would suffice.

Here is a jsbin to demonstrate:

http://jsbin.com/zamavoha/1/edit